# sql table tracker , cant use trigger or sql dependency

Tags: c#, sql

i can't use trigger and  sql dependency.
i don't have permissions on the server.

how can i reach the column change on the table, when table got updated ?

is there any way besides two options?

Comment: Transaction replication? That still uses triggers in the background, but those are managed by the system. If you don't have permission to set up triggers, though, you probably almost certainly have no permission to configure replication either. Ask a DBA, or live with a solution where you'll have to copy and compare data explicitly yourself to see what's new.

Comment: the table has not "modifieddate" column. So when a line updated i can't know which line updated by copy/check. I dont have any information about which line updated.

Comment: You can checksum all data in the row and compare that against an earlier copy. Without a modification timestamp or a trigger you will simply not be able to have any kind of efficient solution.